# Response message is not displayed in the gradio UI which runs a python script for openai chat model

Tags: python, openai-api, gradio

I have the following problem at creation of an openai chatbot model:

The **assistant replies are not displayed in the gradio chatbox**. Only the user input is displayed. There are no errors or warnings in the UI nor in the console.
The response object includes very good assistant's messages, but they are lost on the way to the gradio display.

I am using recently updated version of gradio, python 3.x and the gpt-3.5-turbo-0125 model

Here is the **script function** passed to gradio:

```
def predict(message, history):

    response = get_completion(messages)
    for choice in response.choices:
        if choice.finish_reason == "stop":
            break

        if choice.finish_reason == "tool_calls":

            fn_name = choice.message["function_call"].name
            arguments = choice.message["function_call"].arguments

            function = locals()[fn_name]
            result = function(**arguments)

            messages.append(
                {
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": None,
                    "function_call": {
                        "name": fn_name,
                        "arguments": arguments,
                    },
                }
            )

            messages.append(
                {
                    "role": "function",
                    "name": fn_name,
                    "content": f'{{"result": {str(result)} }}'
                }
            )

        else:
            messages.append(choice.message["content"])

        response = get_completion(messages)
```

Here is the **response object** (includes message I want to see in the UI):

```
ChatCompletion(id='secret', choices=[Choice(finish_reason='stop', index=0, logprobs=None, message=ChatCompletionMessage(content='To calculate the price for Simple Reservations, I need the following information from you:\n\n1. Number of users who will be using the software.\n2. Number of rooms that you want to manage.\n3. Are you a first-time client, or have you used Simple Reservations before?\n\nCan you please provide me with these details?', role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None))]
, created=1708046994, model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0125', object='chat.completion', system_fingerprint='fp_9fdfea22a2', usage=CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=68, prompt_tokens=156, total_tokens=224))
```

Comment: Revoke the id that you leaked in the question immediately!